# HTML Slideshow Image Size Does Not Increase When Changing It's Dimentions

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I'm attempting to increase the size of an image contained in my slider (HOR1) however when I increase it's dimensions to 800 x 600 (for example) it does not seem to increase the size of the image? How might I increase it's size in order to make it flush / fill the entire slideshow?

### HTML Source Code:

```
<div id="content-slider">       
    <ul id="async-slider">
        <li class="slide">
            <div class="three-fifth fl-left" style="width: 425px; height: 242px">
                <h2>Brighter World Lighting - NY</h2>
                <h3><font size="5"><i>"A not just for profit company!"</i></font></h3>
                <p>...</a>
            </div>  

            <img class="fl-right" src="img/logolrg.png" alt="image" width="468" height="329" />      

        </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <div class="three-fifth fl-left">


                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" width: 800px; height: 600px /> 
                <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                <p>...</a>
          </div>    


        </li>
```

Comment: Live Site: www.bwl-ny.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the syntax for your HOR1 image. Take a look at the width and height attributes in logolrg.png, the correct syntax is

```
<img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" width="800" height="600" />
```

You used style syntax in HOR1. That works so long as you wrap them in a style attribute like so:

```
<img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;" />
```

As mentioned by isThisLove, it's typically a better idea to move styles out to an external stylesheet whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you!! That allowed me to increase the size - but it's still not flush - it seems like there's about 2 inches of padding at the top of it preventing it from being flush. Do you know how I might be able to fix that as well?

Comment: It looks like it's bumping down because of the margin-top and line-height styles applied to #async-slider li h2, so those would be the first things to look into. If you make that h2 display: inline; it moves the elements back to the top on my screen, but I'm not sure the exact look you're going for there, so you'll have to play with the details.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;" />
```

or

```
<img class="fl-right" src="img/HOR1.jpg" alt="image" width="800" height="600" />
```

It's better to use external css files, thro.

Comment: Just seconds after me, but +1 for mentioning external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do so:

1) You can increase/decrease the size of an image by using a photo editor(paint,Photoshop..)

2)  
Answer:

- You should always use CSS style attribute:
        **style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"**